# Unable to install bcrypt on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt, ubuntu-20.04

My project has ruby 2.6.5, rails 6 and when i tried to run bundle install, **bcrypt** gem is not installing. I tried **sudo apt-get install ruby-dev** and **sudo apt-get install build-essential** commands to resolve the issue and they were not helpful.
Any one can help on this ?

Below is log for it.

```
Fetching bcrypt-3.1.11.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/mahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/ext/mri
/home/mahesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby -I /home/mahesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210222-10360-1tmu5r0.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/mahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/mahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
compiling crypt_gensalt.c
compiling wrapper.c
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.so

current directory: /home/mahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/bin/mkdir: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:202: .sitearchdir.time] Error 127

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/mahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for 
inspection.
Results logged to /home/mahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/bcrypt- 
3.1.11/gem_make.out
```

Comment: `which mkdir` says /bin/mkdir on my system.  You might have more luck on serverfault as this is not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks @AllanWind You're right. Below command helped me.

sudo ln -s /bin/mkdir /usr/bin/mkdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package looks for `/usr/bin/mkdir` but on a Debian based system the correct path is `/bin/mkdir`.  Op solved the problem by creating a symlink.  It would be better to fix the installer.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!!! `ln -s /bin/mkdir /usr/bin/mkdir` saved me so much time. Thank you